# Need to map two applications under the same base URL in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

We have this application that has one method for POSTs and one method for GETs:

GET:  http://localhost:8080/MyAPP/rest/clients/clientid/

POST: http://localhost:8080/MyAPP/rest/incoming/clientid/

The two methods are very distinct processes, so we want to separate them into two separate applications for simpler change deployments.  Unfortunately we already have upstream and downstream client applications in production and so can't change the URLs in any way.  Is there a way in Tomcat to make that happen?

Comment: So you want two independent .wars deployed on one tomcat instance?

Comment: On Tomcat 8 you can use the `RewriteValve` similar to Apache's mod_rewrite to map the urls to different applications.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to deploy the splited applications into new URLs, e.g.

```
 http://localhost:8080/MyAPPPost/rest/clients/clientid/

 http://localhost:8080/MyAPPGet/rest/clients/clientid/
```

and to have a new application under the old URL, which would acts as proxy, delegate the GET and POST requests appropriately.